# ASP.NET MVC - Authenticating AD users when IIS is not in domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory

Can anyone give me working examples of Active Directory authentication in ASP.NET MVC when the hosting IIS is not in the domain.

Here's the code of my controller. On my machine, which in the domain, I can authenticate without a problem. However, when I publish the app to my IIS server, which is in our LAN but not in the domain, I can no longer authenticate.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web;
using login;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

namespace login.Models
{
    public class AdAuthenticationService
    {
        public class AuthenticationResult
        {
            public AuthenticationResult(string errorMessage = null)
            {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        }

        public String ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
        public Boolean IsSuccess => String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage);
    }

    private readonly IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AdAuthenticationService(IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
    {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }



    public AuthenticationResult SignIn(String username, String password)
    {

        ContextType authenticationType = ContextType.Domain;
        ContextOptions _options = ContextOptions.ServerBind;

        PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(authenticationType, @"DC_hostname:3268");

        bool isAuthenticated = false;
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = null;
        try
        {
            //isAuthenticated = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
            isAuthenticated = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
            if (isAuthenticated)
            {
                userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, username);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            isAuthenticated = false;
            userPrincipal = null;
        }

        if (!isAuthenticated || userPrincipal == null)
        {
            return new AuthenticationResult("Wrong Username or Password.");
        }

        if (userPrincipal.IsAccountLockedOut())
        {

            return new AuthenticationResult("Your account is locked.");
        }

        if (userPrincipal.Enabled.HasValue && userPrincipal.Enabled.Value == false)
        {

            return new AuthenticationResult("Your account is disabled");
        }

        var identity = CreateIdentity(userPrincipal);

        authenticationManager.SignOut(MyAuthentication.ApplicationCookie);
        authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, identity);


        return new AuthenticationResult();
    }


    private ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(UserPrincipal userPrincipal)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(MyAuthentication.ApplicationCookie, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "Active Directory"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userPrincipal.SamAccountName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userPrincipal.SamAccountName));
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userPrincipal.EmailAddress))
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userPrincipal.EmailAddress));
        }

        // add your own claims if you need to add more information stored on the cookie

        return identity;
    }
}
}
```

On my IIS I have Anonymous and Basic Authentication Enabled. Everything else is disabled in terms of AUthentication.

Any help would be appreciated.

José

Comment: Not sure how or even why you'd use AD Authentication from a server that's not in the domain.

Comment: This old snippet should still work, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#35

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Not getting any error. The text "Wrong Username or Password." is being output to the screen as per the code given the condition --> if (!isAuthenticated || userPrincipal == null) ". I've got connectivity to my DC (with tcpview I can see that calls are being made with success) but it is simply not authenticating... there must be something missing... thanks.

Comment: Is `DC_hostname` a domain controller for the domain you're logging into (not another one in the forest)? Is there a reason you're connecting to the global catalog (port 3268) rather than the default LDAP (389)?

Comment: We have users of several domains so I'm pointing to the global catalog. Changed to default ldap port and still can't connect when the app is published to IIS (outside domain). On my development machine (which is a domain computer) everything is ok.

Comment: with remote debugging setup I can now show what error is being thrown...

Comment: This is the error: https://imgur.com/a/YvCu4

Comment: If you want to use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement your device must be in the domain.  If you're outside the domain, you'll have to use LDAP (e.g. [Using LDAP and Active Directory with C# 101](https://auth0.com/blog/using-ldap-with-c-sharp/) or Federation (e.g. [Federated Identity for Web Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff359110.aspx) using something like ADFS.